# Assembly version becomes same in the next day

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

TFS build templates:

I am using the build number format as : `$(BuildDefinitionName)_$(Date:yyyyMMdd)$(Rev:.r)`
 and the Assembly version pattern and Assembly file version pattern as : 1.1.B

So here on the first day the build number goes like 1.1.1, 1.1.2 and 1.1.3 etc

on the next when i build the build number will be same since the Rev: .r will be get reset.

However I need to retain the build number. example when I build the soln today (24-Feb-2014)
the build number is 1.1.1 and if I build again in the next day it should 1.1.2 and then 1.1.3
irrespective of the number of time I build on same day or other days, the build number should be retained

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Change the build number format to $(BuildDefinitionName_$(Rev:.r)

If you don't want the revision to reset every day, then simply don't include the date in the build number string.